# Multiple commands from cmd.exe /k with & does not work

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Apologies if this is answered somewhere, been searching for 30+ mins to no avail.

So I have a batch file, from within it I call:

```
%comspec% /K "CD ..\..\test\java_6_86 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\javac.exe" -classpath TestLib.jar Test1.java"
```

However that does not work.

What I am trying to do is:

(Within a batch file)

1. Open a new command prompt
2. Change the Current Directory to the directory where Test1.java lives
3. Then call the java compiler and have it compile Test1.java

Also, is it possible to tell command where to start, instead of having to do a CD as the fist command?

Thanks,
DoW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what your `%comspec%` is but suppose it is 'cmd' this should do the trick (the `cmd /K` has to be in front of the `javac` call)

```
cd ..\..\test\java_6_86 & cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\javac.exe" -classpath TestLib.jar Test1.java
```

By the way, a two liner would be much more readable

```
cd ..\..\test\java_6_86
cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\javac.exe" -classpath TestLib.jar Test1.java
```

You can of course use absolute pathes to specify your classpath and java Source file and skip the directory change.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, you could use `pushd/popd`. As name suggests, those allow to store current directory, then change to given path (`pushd path`) and then `popd` pops/restores the original current dir. It's useful if you need to temporarily change current directory to do some processing or you want to shield your code from unwanted directory changes (eg. if you call another batch). It's also handy with network paths as it auto-creates a drive letter for it. `Help pushd` will give you full info.